# Show Moment estimator and MLE are the same only for exponential family

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, exponential-family

Show Moment estimator and MLE are the same only for exponential family. I know MM is variant while MLE is not under transformation. Will this be the starting point?